# how to check existence of a core files in directory using Python

Tags: python

I want to parsing some program's log and I want to check the existence of a core file in the log directory.

Assume the `path` is the log directory, and core file names always begins with string `core` (e.g., name is `core.20161027.183805.28273.0001.dmp`). Then is there any directed API I can use to check a core file in the `path` directory? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use the built-in `glob` module:

```
import glob
if glob.glob('/path/to/dir/core*'):
    print('At least one core file present in /path/to/dir')
```

More reading here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Answer (score 1):

This may be dupe, is this the solution?

```
import os
os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,corename))
```

Comment: I accept another answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Also os lib can do the trick for you, returns true or false

`import os`

`os.path.exists(dir_or_file_to_check)`